# #/bin/sh in one line

Tags: shell, unix, haskell, ffmpeg

I'm working on some Haskell project using [FFmpeg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFmpeg). I need to batch create from a media folder with [MP4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_14) files and create screenshots from all of them. I got the code and am using it on a terminal in Unix. It works, but how do I make it in one line to be executed in system "xxxx" in Haskell?

If not using several system"xx"...

```
#/bin/sh
for i in $(ls *.mp4)
do
    ffmpeg -i $i -vframes 7 -y -ss 10 -s 150x150 -an -sameq -f image2 -r 1/5  $i%1d.jpg
done
```

I tried:

```
import System.Cmd
function = do{system "#/bin/sh";
system "for i in $(ls *.mp4)";
system "do";
system "ffmpeg -i $i -vframes 7 -y -ss 10 -s 150x150 -an -sameq -f image2 -r 1/5  $i%1d.jpg";
system "done";}
```

but it gives a error:

```
-vframes: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: Syntax error: "done" unexpected
```

Comment: The second fragment creates four separate subshells. You might try to cram it all into one line. Or use a wrapper-script like the first snippet, but with `#!/bin/sh` as a shebang, as the other replier pointed out.

Comment: Note that `for i in *.mp4` is more efficient than `for i in $(ls *.mp4)`.  And it will work on systems where `/bin/sh` isn't a symlink to `/bin/bash` (`$(command)` is bash-specific).

Comment: @wildplasser: Both versions need either a semicolon or a new-line.

Comment: @KeithThompson `$(command)` isn't bash-specific, it is POSIX.  Also , not only is `*.mp4` more efficient, it's not broken like `$(ls *.mp4)` is because the latter will break on files with spaces in their names.  The only problem is that `*.mp4` does not recurse into subdirs, but see my answer on how to get that to work. Unfortunately, that *is* Bash 4 specific.  The portable version is to use a `while read -d ''` loop with `find ... -print0` feeding file names via process substitution.

Comment: @GoodGuyGreg FYI, the answer you chose is broken, see my comment above as to why

Comment: @SiegeX: Yes, it's POSIX -- but not all systems have a POSIX-compliant `/bin/sh`.  (Solaris 9 doesn't, for example.)

Comment: @KeithThompson that may be true, but so is the fact that it is not bash specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Bash 4.X Solution

```
system "/bin/bash -c 'shopt -s globstar; for i in **.mp4; do ffmpeg -i \"$i\" -vframes 7 -y -ss 10 -s 150x150 -an -sameq -f image2 -r 1/5  \"$i\"%1d.jpg; done'"
```

1. You don't need #!/bin/bash with `system` (don't forget the bang !)
2. Quote your variables otherwise files with spaces in their names wont work
3. Don't use `ls` like that, it will break when it comes across a file with spaces in its name

#### Posix Solution

```
system "find /some/path -type f -name \"*.mp4\" -exec sh -c 'for f; do ffmpeg -i \"$f\" -vframes 7 -y -ss 10 -s 150x150 -an -sameq -f image2 -r 1/5  \"$f%1d.jpg\"; done' _ {} +"
```

Comment: `*.mp4` should be sufficient too, no?

Comment: Well... I suppose the `ls` solution behaves differently if you have a directory called `foo.mp4`, but that seems unlikely :)

Comment: `*.mp4` is sufficient if you don't care about recursing into subdirs and only the current directory.  The `ls` solution breaks with files that have spaces in their names, regardless of quoting.

Comment: Yeah, the quoting issues are nasty. The `ls` version doesn't recurse into subdirectories itself, though.

Comment: I dont have the "shopt" _ "/bin/sh: shopt: not found"
What code I need to install it? I have bash 4.1.5
but the rest of the code works fine

Comment: @GoodGuyGreg Ah, right. `system()` is hard coded to call `/bin/sh` so we need to tell it to call `bash` explicitly. See the updated answer.  You might just go with the Posix version if you want to be portable, though.

Comment: Now it works fine, but the **Posix Solution** is somewhere wrong
_/bin/sh: Syntax error: redirection unexpected_
In both expressions the third **"** in _\"$i\"%1d.jpg"_ shouldn't be there

Comment: @GoodGuyGreg Ok so after some digging, apparently `-print0` is not posix nor is the `-d` flag to read.  The posix approach is therefore one call to `find` which in turn exec's `/bin/sh` and passes to that shell the list of files it found.  That shell then loops through those files to run ffmpeg.  A bit unwieldy, but it *is* portable =).  See updated answer

Comment: Perfect! But something inconvenient happened. so using in the _music.mp3_ it results in "music.mp31.jpg" "music.mp32.jpg" .... all fine but compiling the latex it don't recognize the extension, `LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .mp41.jpg` so is there a way to remove the extension (remove last 4 chars _.mp4_) so I can add the %1d.jpg and becomes _music1.jpg_?

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that you're trying to execute each line of your script as a separate, independent invocation of the shell. You just need to do it all with one `system` call, and separate each line of the script with `\n`:

```
system "for i in $(ls *.mp4)\ndo\n..."
```

but you can write the shell command on one logical line, instead:

```
system "for i in $(ls *.mp4); do ...; done"
```

The first line (which should be `#!/bin/sh`, by the way) is not necessary when using `system`.

I'm not sure why you want to use Haskell for this purpose, though, if you're just going to execute a single shell script. You should write the loop over the directory contents in Haskell, and only call out to the system to do an individual conversion. At the very least, you should probably put this script into its own file and invoke it with `system "sh convert.sh"` or similar.

(If you want a more convenient syntax for multi-line strings like these scripts in Haskell, try the [interpolatedstring-perl6](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/interpolatedstring-perl6) or [string-qq](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/string-qq) packages.)

Comment: I'm using haskell not only for "create screenshots" but also create some pdf's with info of music and video and I need to insert the screenshots in pdf. With this code is much easier

Answer (score 4):

First, It's `#!/bin/sh`. Notice the exclamation mark.

Second, you're trying to execute a series of commands one after another, so no state is kept between them. Try to execute it as a single command:

```
function = system "for i in $(ls *.mp4); do ffmpeg -i $i -vframes 7 -y -ss 10 -s 150x150 -an -sameq -f image2 -r 1/5  $i%1d.jpg; done"
```

Another option is to save your whole script, with the `#!` corrected, as a `.sh` file, make it executable and:

```
function = system "./myscript.sh"
```

Comment: Note that it'll need to be `./myscript.sh` (unless it's put into the `$PATH`).

Answer (score 2):

You should not echo the shell script like this but create a shell command like this:

```
system "for i in $(ls *.mp4); do ffmpeg -i $i -vframes 7 -y -ss 10 -s 150x150 -an -sameq -f image2 -r 1/5  $i%1d.jpg; done"
```